# How can I re-parse an XML document at set intervals?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I have built an area on my client's website that displays a song that is currently playing, as parsed from an XML file via PHP. However, my client wants the song to auto-refresh itself instead of him having to manually refresh the page.

I played around with parsing the file using jQuery.get() and also .ajax(), but because of the way the XML file is structured, it seems as though I can only get the artist and the name squashed into one string, or when I try to be specific it only returns [object Object].

I haven't even tried to tackle having the song's length be calculated and then refresh the feed based on that length. I may not seeing as this is apparently such an issue for me.

Any help or general guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Example working PHP code (obviously, non-AJAX):

```
<?php
    $recentlyPlayed = simplexml_load_file('http://publicapi.streamtheworld.com/public/nowplaying?mountName=ABCDFM&numberToFetch=1&eventType=track');
    $trackTitle = $recentlyPlayed->{'nowplaying-info'}[0]->property[1];
    $trackArtist = $recentlyPlayed->{'nowplaying-info'}[0]->property[0];
    echo "<h6>" . $trackArtist . "<span class=\"song-title\">" . $trackTitle . "</span></h6>";
?>
```

I've tried several different things to get this to work, but it seems the initial obstacle is trying to reference the data in the XML file using the attributes, rather than the node-names. The nodes are all named the same, and it's the attributes that differentiate them. So, as such this code will render correctly, unless the artist/song title are blank, then it renders the third field which is sort of cryptically-named "cue_time_start".

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval("songPull()",1000);
    });

    function songPull() {
        $.get(
            "http://publicapi.streamtheworld.com/public/nowplaying?mountName=ABCDFM&numberToFetch=1&eventType=track", 
            "xml",
            function(data) {
                $(data).find("nowplaying-info").each(function(){
                    var artist = $(this).find("property").eq(0).text();
                    var title = $(this).find("property").eq(1).text();
                    $('body').html("<h1>" + artist + "<small class=\"song-title\">" + title + "</small></h1>");
                    console.log (artist);
                    console.log (title);
                });
            }
        );
    }
</script>
<body>

</body>
```

Any guidance, advice or examples of best practices when trying to do this sort of thing would be so very greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want, but you could simply use attribute selectors to extract the data you want out of your XML document.

http://jsfiddle.net/P8dc6/

```
$.get("http://publicapi.streamtheworld.com/public/nowplaying?mountName=KROXFM&numberToFetch=1&eventType=track", 
    "xml",
    function(data) {
        var $nowPlaying = $(data).find('nowplaying-info');
        console.log($nowPlaying.find('[name=track_artist_name]').text());
        console.log($nowPlaying.find('[name=cue_title]').text());
    }
);
```

Also, never pass a `string` to `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, you can just pass the function reference directly:

```
setInterval(songPull ,1000);
```